# Can I visualize the outer box of 3D plot?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

My current plot looks something like this now,

image1

[image]

But I'd like to add outer boarders so that I can have a closed box.
Like this,

image2

[image]

I am currently using Python3.6,

**matplotlib.pyplot**

I know that MATLAB gives such options(these images are from MATLAB documentation), so I thought matplotlib may provide the same. But I have failed to find any documentations regarding this issue.

Do I have such options to visualize the outer box, or should I use another package instead?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the method [`set_frame_on`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#appearance) from the class `Axes` on the current axes.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working unfortunately..
Guess matplotlib does not have such options for 3d plots